# using ''require'' or synonyms in a cover letter

Tags: verbs, synonyms, formality

I have a doubt about the correct use of the verb **to require** and its synonyms in a cover letter.
My doubt is: *require* sounds almost like it's something that you are *forced* to do (therefore expresses a negative feeling/connotation).

So, what are the best synonyms to say in a cover letter that a jobs ''requires'' you to have multiple roles and skills?

I am tempted between *involve* and *call for*. But since it's a formal cover letter, I want to make sure I insert the correct one
(btw, I'm Italian).

The sentence I have in mind is:
**My current position as a DA is a multifaceted position that *requires* me to play a broad range of roles using a full spectrum of skills.**

Would it be better to replace *requires* with one of the following: *involves/calls for/demands/necessitates/*??? 
Which one would best fit into a formal cover letter but at the same time **express a *positive feeling***???

Thank you so much in advance. Still learn English :)

Comment: I don't see any negative connotations related to `require` with your example sentence. However, if you must replace it, you can say `...lets me play` or `...allows me to play`. Side note: the part after `play` sounds a little verbose to me.

Comment: "demands" seems even more forceful than "requires". "requires" is the usual word used in this context.